Run "scrot -" from Openbox
I'm trying to add a new keybinding to the rc.xml of my Openbox WM. The code is as follows:
<keybind key="Print">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>scrot -s - | xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png</command>
  </action>
</keybind>

But nothing happens. It should be also noted that the line itself, run from the shell, works just fine.
Alternatively, if I put into my xml something like
scrot '/tmp/%F_%T_$wx$h.png' -e 'xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i $f'

everything works as intended though with writing an image to the drive. What's the problem?
UPD: Ok, possible solution. Another problem is to place && operator correctly inside XML since &amp; is rendered literally, not as operator.
